# How to use terminal in "incognito mode'?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I am using freya. I prefer to use *terminal* for  my work. (from copy to installation). In elementary, when I close terminal, it will be still on the previous directory.

How can I disable this feature? Also can I use terminal in *incognito* mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disable Previous Tabs**

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings remember-tabs false
```

**Incognito Mode**

```
unset HISTFILE
```

See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/149535/how-do-i-clear-history-of-the-bash-logs-also-do-not-log-any-of-my-users-bash) answer for how to make this permanent.