# How to disable last working directory in pantheon-terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I work a lot in terminal, and am not a fan of having new tabs and new windows opening my previous working directory. I would like to change pantheon-terminal to open my home directory each time.

I found the following keys in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.pantheon.terminal.gschema.xml and changed default to equal false, and yet I am still getting the same behavior.

```
    <key name="follow-last-tab" type="b">
    <default>false</default>
    <summary>Open last active tab path on new tab.</summary>
    <description>Defines whether a new tab should have the path of the last active tab.</description>
    </key>
    <key name="remember-tabs" type="b">
    <default>false</default>
    <summary>Defines whether the terminal should remember tabs.</summary>
    <description>Defines whether the terminal should remember the last open tabs.</description>
    </key>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: refer http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/how-to-use-terminal-in-incognito-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use terminal in "incognito mode'?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/how-to-use-terminal-in-incognito-mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must actually change those keys in gsettings not in the gschema. So use for example the terminal with:
`gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings follow-last-tab false`

Comment: Much better solution!

Comment: Interestingly, I went into [Configuator] (https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Configurator/), navigated to org>pantheon>terminal>settings.... and the "follow-last-tab" and "remember-tabs" keys were already set to false. However, using gsettings in command line worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

A work-around: add `cd ~` to your bashrc file.